# ria services + jquery

Tags: jquery, ria

I have used `ria.js` and upshot but I get the same error in jquery:

> object is undefined

This error is thrown from jQuery on line 630, inside

> each:function
>   -->   length = object.length

My javascript can call the domainservice and have the `json` response, and in the debugger I have this response:

```
{
    "GetTodoItemsResult": {
        "TotalCount": 4,
        "RootResults": [{
            "IsDone": false,
            "Title": "Todo item 1",
            "TodoItemId": 1
        }, {
            "IsDone": false,
            "Title": "Todo item 2",
            "TodoItemId": 2
        }, {
            "IsDone": false,
            "Title": "Todo item 3",
            "TodoItemId": 3
        }, {
            "IsDone": false,
            "Title": "Todo item 4",
            "TodoItemId": 4
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it ! just add transmitMetadata="true" in web.config :